# how to read a register in device driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

in a linux device driver, in the init function for the device, I tried reading an address (which is SMMUv3 device for arm64) like below.

```
uint8_t *addr1;

addr1 = ioremap(0x09050000, 0x20000);  
printk("SMMU_AIDR     : 0x%X\n", *(addr1 + 0x1c));
```

but I get `Internal error: synchronous external abort: 96000010 [#1] SMP` error.
Is it not permitted to map an address to virtual address using ioremap and just reading that address?

Comment: You need to use the mmio register access functions (readb, writeb, etc.) to read/write the addresses.

Comment: Hardware has different types of addresses for different purposes. Here's an article that explains some of the why:  https://lwn.net/Articles/653585/

Comment: In this case, it was because of the access width was wrong. I understand, after ioremap, we can access even portio using memory operation(like the answer I posted). And in arm64 there is no portio (no in,out command).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I gave a fixed value 0x78789a9a to SMMU IDR[2] register. (at offset 0x8, 32 bit register. This is possible because it's qemu.)
SMMU starts at 0x09050000 and it has address space 0x20000.

```
__iomem uint32_t *addr1 = NULL;

static int __init my_driver_init(void)
{
...
addr1 = ioremap(0x09050000, 0x20000); // smmuv3
printk("SMMU_IDR[2]     : 0x%X\n", readl(addr1 +0x08/4));
..}
```

This is the output when the driver is initialized.(The value is read ok)

```
[  453.207261] SMMU_IDR[2]     : 0x78789A9A
```

The first problem was that the access width was wrong for that address. Before, it was defined as `uint8_t *addr1;` and I used `printk("SMMU_AIDR : 0x%X\n", *(addr1 + 0x1c))` so it was reading byte when it was not allowed by the SMMU model.

Second problem (I think this didn't cause the trap because arm64 provides memory mapped io) was that I used memory access(pointer dereferencing) for memory mapped IO registers. As people commented, I should have used readl function. (Mainly because to make the code portable. readl works also for iomap platforms like x86_64. using the mmio adderss as pointer will not work on such platforms. I later found that readl function takes care of the memory barrier problem too).
ADD : I fixed volatile to __iomem for variable addr1.(thanks @0andriy)

Comment: You have to really read documentation. In all your Qs regarding Linux kernel programming you make a lot of mistakes of different severity. Here, for example, you missed I/O operations, i.e. `readl()`. Possible that you mapped wrongly the memory (if it's a **memory** and not **MMIO**). Second, use `void __iomem *...` instead of your creativity. And so on...

Comment: @0andriy execuse me, it was really memory mapped registers. and after ioremap, I can use memory operations (for example, *addr = 0x1). Am I wrong?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/volatile-considered-harmful.html

Comment: @0andriy thanks I fixed volatile -> __iomem. also I changed memory access to readl. (but I remember seeing in a video, using memory access is good in this case. Please see near 51:00 saying load/store works for mmio. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87FnEUOgRiY&list=PLlrqp8hxLfoqSIQFrGbAM5lv5uAnZBB61&index=8)

Comment: @ChanKim See LDD3 [9.4.2. Accessing I/O Memory](https://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4.shtml#chp-9-sect-4.2) for why you should not dereference mmio addresses directly.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks again, I now fully realized why I should use readl, writel for iomem. what a slow learner I am.. I updated the answer.